# Pandas duplicated shows non-duplicated rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

As you can see in my following code, I call `duplicated` to find duplicate rows. It says that 2877 items are duplicated, but from what I see in the results (`head()`) they are not!

What's the problem?

```
>>> df = pd.read_table('xAttr_validation_no_dups.tsv')
>>> dups = df[df.duplicated(subset=['input_text', 'target_text'], keep=False)]
>>> len(dups)
2877
>>> dups.head()
    prefix                                      input_text   target_text
13   xAttr  PersonX از ___ برای کمک به PersonY تشکر می کند      thankful
14   xAttr  PersonX از ___ برای کمک به PersonY تشکر می کند      grateful
15   xAttr  PersonX از ___ برای کمک به PersonY تشکر می کند  appreciative
36   xAttr           PersonX برای دریافت ___ پرداخت می کند          rich
251  xAttr             PersonX ابتدا ___ را در نظر می گیرد    thoughtful
```

Comment: What if simply doing `df[df.duplicated(keep=False)]` ?

Comment: Have you tried to `.sort_values(subset=['input_text', 'target_text'])` the data? Maybe it works, but you just dont see the duplicates in the head, because of the sorting. Your data seems to be sorted by index currently. Also your title seems to be misleading.

Comment: @KarnKumar It returns the same results as above.

Comment: @Ahmad, if you do `df[df[['input_text', 'target_text']].duplicated() == True]`  then .

Comment: @Andreas please offert the complete code, where I should call that `sort_values`?

Comment: Try: `dups.sort_values(subset=['input_text', 'target_text']).head()` and post the result pls.

Comment: @Andreas yes, however, I must use `by` instead of `subset`. But it returns rows that have duplicates.

Comment: @Ahmad, ok, this means, everythign works as it should, there are no bugs. The duplicates you are looking for are just further down the rows, so with `.head()`you dont see them yet.

Comment: @Andreas The misleading part was that it returned rows that their first columns was sorted or had similar values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.duplicated()
```

returns the result in the same order as the initial dataframe.
This means, that it is most likely that your duplicates are further down in the dataframe. Since `.head()` only shows the top 5, this might not be enough to actually see them.

Also the odd number of 2877 is possible if there are duplicates with an odd amount, e.g. 3x thankful.

To get a better idea if it worked, you can sort before using head:

```
dups.sort_values(by=['input_text', 'target_text']).head()
```

To answer the question in your title, how to get only uniques, you can invert the boolean mask you get with duplicated by using `~`:

```
df[~df.duplicated(subset=['input_text', 'target_text'], keep=False)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think below should work as you are doing it on more than a column:

```
df[df[['input_text', 'target_text']].duplicated() == True]
```

Comment: @Ahmad, Can you place few lines of your dataframe to reproduce

Comment: Why minus voting?